# Loop through and list a 2 column db table from Tinytds via ruby with column1 values as headings and column2 values as a list

Tags: ruby, loops, tiny-tds

I've been trying to learn the basics of loops and I'm getting there but I'm struggling to get my brain around the following requirement where, for example, I've got data from a database table via tinytds, such that key/values are hashed into an array it seems(? - beginner here, so hope my terminology is correct!):-

The data is such that the values from one 'column' of the db table is repeated many times, whilst the values of the 2nd 'column' are unique.

Therefore, rather than simply creating a table in HTML for output that simply has 2 columns with column1 showing the same line of text over and over (before the next unique string lists over and over), I'd like to present the information so that unique string values from column1 are headings and the values of column2 are then listed beneath.

In my mind, I think what I'm trying to achieve is to loop through column1 for each unique string, output that value, whilst running an inner loop to list all values for column2 where column1 is 'string', moving on to the next unique value of column1,output that value, then loop through column2 again to list all values where column1 is 'string2' etc.

Hope that makes sense as I'm struggling to know how to explain in the correct terminology.

Thanks.

For example, if my 2 columns from my database table were as follows:-.

Column1
Q1
Q1
Q1
Q2
Q2
Q3
Q3
Q3

Column2
A1
A2
A3
A4
A5
A6
A7
A8

How could I loop (or whatever is best) through to be able to present the output such as:-

Q1
 A1
 A2
 A3

Q2
 A4
 A5

Q3
 A6
 A7
 A8

I can write the HTML side to format the output, I just can't figure out the ruby side.

For a single loop I've picked up from tiny_tds examples the following ruby (the html here is just to test placement for now):-

```
<% narrative.each do |question| %>
<span><%=question.values[1] %></span>
<br/>   
<% end %>
```

That allows me to list all the values for slot 2 (is that correct terminology?) and I could do something like:-

```
<% narrative.each do |question| %>
<span><%=question.values[0] %></span><span><%=question.values[1] %></span>
<br/>   
<% end %>
```

To show both side by side, but what I'm wanting to do is be more like:-

```
<h1>Question1 goes here</h1>
<ul>
<li>Answer 1</li>
<li>Answer 2</li>
<li>Answer 3</li>
</ul>
<h1>Question2 goes here</h1>
<ul>
<li>Answer 4</li>
<li>Answer 5</li>
</ul>
```

etc.

Comment: give some examples,dear.we can't guess how your data looks like?

Comment: They say a picture is worth a thousand words. In this case, showing some code you've written to let us see what you are talking about, will tell us much.

Comment: Hi, I've written no code, no idea how to.  But apologies for the lack of an example, I couldn't figure out how to list things in the post as I agree a visual would make a lot more sense. I'll try and figure it out.

Comment: Added some additional text to hopefully make me clearer.  Thanks.

Comment: how `Q3
A6
A7
A8` it comes? what logic you used?

Comment: Hi Priti, typo in my example, there shouldn't be Q4.  I'll amend that.  Is that what you're refering to? Otherwise, I don't understand your question.

Comment: @lad33 Given the answer and check it out by your self.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep it simple, do it this way, just giving the logic, in stead of the puts add your html tags

```
a1 = [:Q1,:Q1,:Q1,:Q2,:Q2,:Q3,:Q3,:Q3] 
a2 = [:A1,:A2,:A3,:A4,:A5,:A6,:A7,:A8]

a3 = a1.zip a2
#=>[[:Q1, :A1], [:Q1, :A2], [:Q1, :A3], [:Q2, :A4], [:Q2, :A5], [:Q3, :A6], [:Q3, :A7], [:Q3, :A8]]

a3.each_with_index do |e, i|
  puts "#{e[0] if e[0] != a3[i-1][0]} #{e[1]}"
end

=>
Q1 A1
 A2
 A3
Q2 A4
 A5
Q3 A6
 A7
 A8
```

Comment: thanks peter, I've dropped your code into my erb page and taken a look.  Unfortunately I don't know enough Ruby to understand what's happening in the puts line to be able to break it out into my html tags.  I can see just using your code from my results however that my tweaked code so far:-
    <li style="color: green;"><%= "#{e[0] if e[0] != a4[i-1][0]} #{e[1]}" %></li>

results in Q1 and A1 being in the same list item, then A2 n a new list item, then A3 in a new list item.

Comment: what is between #{} is a Ruby expression, the first expression gives the question if it differs from the one before, the seconds gives always the answer. in my example they are just separated by a space, you have to mangle your tags in between

Comment: wondered if you could help me a little more, have a new scenario and struggling to amend the code you provided. this time I need to check through two hash pairs within an array so I can check to see if the value of the 1st hash repeats and if not, show it, as well as list the values of the 2nd hash...so taking your #{e[0] if e[0] != a4[i-1][0]} as example, I can list the specific values using #{e.values[0]} and #{e.values[1]} but it's the code to get at the previous value that I'm struggling with i.e != a4[i-1](this_bit_here). I tried a4[i-1]e.values[0] but doesn't work...

Comment: I get a NoMethodError for this "undefined method '[]' for #", any pointers you could provide would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Okay! I think below would help you to reach to your goal:

```
>> Column1 = [:Q1,:Q1,:Q1,:Q2,:Q2,:Q3,:Q3,:Q3] 
=> [:Q1, :Q1, :Q1, :Q2, :Q2, :Q3, :Q3, :Q3]
>> Column2 = [:A1,:A2,:A3,:A4,:A5,:A6,:A7,:A8]
=> [:A1, :A2, :A3, :A4, :A5, :A6, :A7, :A8]
>> h = Column1.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)){|i,ob| ob[i] = ob[i] + 1 }
=> {:Q1=>3, :Q2=>2, :Q3=>3}
>> enu = Column2.to_enum
=> #<Enumerator: [:A1, :A2, :A3, :A4, :A5, :A6, :A7, :A8]:each>
>> h1 = h.each_with_object(Hash.new([])){|(k,v),ob| v.times{ ob[k] = ob[k].dup.push(enu.next) } }
=> {:Q1=>[:A1, :A2, :A3], :Q2=>[:A4, :A5], :Q3=>[:A6, :A7, :A8]}
>> h1.each{|k,v| puts k,v}
Q1
A1
A2
A3
Q2
A4
A5
Q3
A6
A7
A8
=> {:Q1=>[:A1, :A2, :A3], :Q2=>[:A4, :A5], :Q3=>[:A6, :A7, :A8]}
```

Or you could do also as below:

```
a1 = [:Q1,:Q1,:Q1,:Q2,:Q2,:Q3,:Q3,:Q3] 
a2 = [:A1,:A2,:A3,:A4,:A5,:A6,:A7,:A8]

a3 = a1.zip(a2).group_by{|i| i[0]}
a3.each{|k,v| v.flatten!.delete(k); puts [k,v]}
```

Comment: Please accept it if you think this answer helped you to reach to your goal.

Comment: Getting there I think, thanks.  I can't quite figure out the last bit however. I've tweaked your code as follows:-
<% h1.each do |k,v| %>
<span style="color:orange;"><h3><%= k %></h3><li><%= v %></li></span>
<% end %>

to try and get the display correct but each of my strings are appearing as one big list item within what appears to be an array.

Looks a bit like this:-
* ["A1","A2","A3"]....
rather than, as intending:-
*A1
*A2
*A3

Comment: @lad33 How that `*` comes with  `*A1 *A2 *A3` ?

Comment: sorry, * was meant to be my bullet item (from <li>), I see that it can confuse!

Comment: @lad33 try in your `irb` first- `puts(1,2)` and then `puts([1,2])`. and look at the output. Hope you will understand how `puts` print array elements.

Comment: Both results look the same?